# Python program to find a word ladder transforming "four" to "five"

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, pathfinding

I saw [this Puzzling problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/as-easy-as-three-two-one-how-fast-can-you-go-from-five-to-four) and thought I would try to write a Python program to solve it. The task is to transform "four" to "five", forming a new four-letter word at each step, replacing one letter at each step, in as few steps as possible.

But turns out I don't know how to optimize recursion, so I'm posting here for help. I'm mostly just confused on why the code to change the `past` needs to be at the top of the function, but I would also like advice on how to speed this up in general. Right now it takes about 10x as long for each step up `max_depth` gets on my computer.

There won't be any matches until you change `max_depth` - I didn't want anyone copy-pasting and lagging out. There should be a solution at depth 5, according to Puzzling. However, my `words` file doesn't have the `Foud` or the word `Fous`, which that answer uses. Bumping up to `max_depth` six will take my computer ~10 minutes, which I don't want to try yet.

```py
def hamming(string1, string2):
    assert len(string1) == len(string2)
    return sum(char1 != char2 for char1, char2 in zip(string1, string2))

max_depth = 3
start_word = "five"
end_word = "four"
all_words = open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r").read().lower().splitlines()
all_words = list(filter(lambda word: word.isalpha(), all_words))
all_words = list(filter(lambda word: len(word) == len(start_word), all_words))

sequences = []

def search(current_word, past = []):
    # Needs to be first to be fast for some reason
    past = past[:]
    past.append(current_word)

    if len(past) > max_depth:
        sequences.append(past)
        return

    for word in all_words:
        if hamming(word, current_word) == 1 and word not in past:
            search(word, past)

search(start_word)

sequences = [sequence[:sequence.index(end_word) + 1] for sequence in sequences if end_word in sequence]

if len(sequences) == 0:
    print("No matches")
else:
    print(min(sequences, key=len))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By performing recursion, you are performing a depth-first search of four-letter words. However, this task involves finding a shortest path, and shortest-path problems are generally better done using breadth-first search. With BFS, the first solution you encounter will be an optimal solution — which is not the case with DFS.

Comment: How would I implement that?

Comment: There are [plenty of word ladder solutions to study on this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=word+ladder+is%3Aquestion) already. There are also many [tag:breadth-first-search] implementations you can study.

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well. Runs in under 6 seconds now.